# c - Array which contains multiple table with one malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

So, what I have to do is to create an array which will contain the multiple table of the number N, IE:

```
"Enter a number = 6"
"1 2 3 4 5 6"
"2 4 6 8 10 12" and so on untill 36
```

This is my code:

```
int * initiallizeArray(int * rows)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int * twoDArray = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", rows);
    twoDArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*rows * *rows));
    for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < *rows; j++)
        {
            //twoDArray[i * *rows + j] =
        }
    }
    return twoDArray;
}
```

The line with the "//" is what I don't know what to implement inside it
Basically it loops all over the array, but I don't know what to put into the specific cell

Comment: NeXoR.  Curious: who or what text suggested the `(int*)` casting in `twoDArray = (int*)malloc(...`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should work:

```
int * initiallizeArray(int * rows)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int * twoDArray;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", rows);
    twoDArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * (*rows));
    for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < *rows; j++)
        {
            twoDArray[i * (*rows) + j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
        }
    }
    return twoDArray;
}
```

Comment: That's it, j +1 * i + 1, Ty

Comment: If `*rows > 2`, `twoDArray[i * (*rows) + j] = ...` attempts to write beyond allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

Since `twoDArray` is in fact *not* a two-dimensional array, you're probably better off renaming it to something more clear. Casting the return value of `malloc` is not recommended, since it is unnecessary and could introduce a bug if you change the type of the pointer you're allocating. The body of the for loop is simple enough: `(i + 1) * (j + 1)`.

```
int* initiallizeArray(int* rows)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int* mult_table = NULL;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", rows);
    mult_table = malloc((sizeof *mult_table) * (*rows) * (*rows));
    for (i = 0; i < *rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < *rows; j++)
        {
            mult_table[i * (*rows) + j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
        }
    }
    return mult_table;
}
```

Comment: Good answer:  minor point: Better to  use `malloc(sizeof(int) * (*rows) * (*rows));` considering types and reduced chance of overflow.

Comment: @chux Is that because `sizeof(int)` is a `size_t` and thus bigger than an `int`?

Comment: @chux can correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the issue is that with `(*rows) * (*rows) * sizeof(int)` the multiplication of two `int`s on the left occurs first, with the possibility of overflow if their values are large. With `sizeof(int) * (*rows) * (*rows)` the multiplication of a `size_t` and an `int` occurs first, so the `int` and the result of the first multiplication are converted to `size_t` (assuming `size_t` is larger than an `int`), reducing the possibility of overflow.

Comment: @DavidBowling C doesn't specify the order of operations in an expression. `a * b * c` and `c * b * a` have the same overflow possibilities.

Comment: @Barmar-- I realize that the order of operations in an expression in general is not specified, but from C11 §6.5.5/1 a __multiplicative-expression__ is (in this instance) __multiplicative-expression * cast-expression__, from which I take it that multiplication associates from the left in C. I am may be wrong here, but that is how I read the Standard on this.

Comment: @Barmar Disagree with [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297629/c-array-which-contains-multiple-table-with-one-malloc/43297781?noredirect=1#comment73662476_43297781) as the various type conversions affect the product calculation. `1.0 * INT_MAX * INT_MAX` is not the same as `INT_MAX * INT_MAX * 1.0`.

Comment: Associativity is not the same as order of operation.

Comment: @iafisher `size_t` is certainly wider than `int` (although C does not specify that - I have never seen a counter example).  The point is that by doing `a_size_t * b_int * c_int` vs `b_int * c_int * a_size_t`, each product, in the first case, is calculated using the wider of `size_t` and `int`.  In the 2nd case, `int * int` may overflow large values that would not overflow `size_t` math.